# Perl: value-mapping in a "perl'ish" way

Tags: perl

I like to map content from one presentation to another and I am looking for a "perl'ish" way to do it.

**Sample:**

```
"ok" -> 1 
"nok" -> 0 
else -> -1
```

My solution is clear but not very elegant. And it is a pain if there are more than 3 possible mappings (0, 1, -1).

```
my $val = "ok";
if ($val eq "ok")
{
    $val = 1;
}
elsif ($val eq "nok")
{
    $val = 0;
}
else
{
    $val = -1;
}
```

I can use a hash but I still need to handle the else-part.

```
$val = "ok";
my %h = ("ok" => 1, "nok" => 0);
if (defined ($h {$val})
{
    $val = $h {$val};
}
else
{
    $val = -1;
}
```

Any way to do it in a one-liner but still keep it readable??

Thanks!

Comment: `$val = $h{$val} // -1`

Comment: @Borodin: Oh. Snap :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `exists` is probably a safer check than `defined`.

```
my %translate = (ok => 1, nok => 0);

$val = exists $translate{$val} ? $translate{$val} : -1;
```

But if you can be sure that none of the hash values will ever be `undef`, you can use the "defined-or" operator:

```
$val = $translate{$val} // -1;
```